# .net core 2.1 MVC - External Authentication for google not working

Tags: asp.net-core

I have to integrate to several external authentication provider in my ASP.NET Core application.

- **Facebook** authentication is working fine.
- However facing issue with **Google** Authentication

```
var info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

The above line of code returns nulls in case of Google. But works fine for Facebook.

Added Google Authentication in `Start.cs`, Page redirects to Google and it returns back to **ExternalLoginCallback** but it fails to fetched the value from cookies:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    var config = Configuration.GetSection("GAuth").Get<AuthSetting>();
    googleOptions.ClientId = config.ClientId;
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = config.ClientSecret;
    //googleOptions.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs";
});
```

Your help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Issue  resolved after adding line 
```googleOptions.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after adding below line in startup.cs class

````
googleOptions.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";```
````